# The multi-part payload was malformed

Tags: image, post, multipartform-data, onenote, onenote-api

Endpoint: POST [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/sections/{section-id}/pages](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/sections/%7Bsection-id%7D/pages)

Request header:
key:Content-Type value:multipart/form-data; boundary=MyAppPartBoundary

Request Body:
--MyAppPartBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Presentation"
Content-Type: text/html

```
/*<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>A page with an image: Image binary data</title>
    <meta name="created" value="2015-11-11T12:45:00.000-8:00"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>This page displays the uploaded image.</p>
    <img src="name:image-block-name" alt="a cool image" width="500">

  </body>



</html>
```

--MyAppPartBoundary

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MyAppPictureId"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

...9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwMEBQ...

--MyAppPartBoundary--*/

Response Preview:
{
"error": {
"code": "20011",
"message": "The multi-part payload was malformed.",
"innerError": {
"date": "2023-11-20T13:59:19",
"request-id": "df177375-fe0e-46f4-b871-367fa0d7a144",
"client-request-id": "da2ecc33-a170-262b-a124-a688e7025889"
}
}
}

I was trying to update a binary data(base64) of an image but it keep on showing the same error please let me know where iam going the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried out your code.
You need to change
-`-MyAppPartBoundary Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Presentation" Content-Type: text/html`
to

```
--MyAppPartBoundary<br>
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Presentation"<br>
Content-Type: text/html
```

and

```
--MyAppPartBoundary

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MyAppPictureId" Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

to

```
--MyAppPartBoundary<br>
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MyAppPictureId"<br>
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

Also make sure you are using CRLF as line returns. Basically the API is really picky about line spacings.